# How can I share images on Facebook via default image viewer

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, facebook

Can I share images directly from Ubuntu 13.10 default image viewer? Or are there any other applications that can do it?

I don't want to open a browser, navigate to Facebook and upload there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found two methods.

Method 1: sharing from Ubuntu One : [OmgUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/12/ubuntu-one-adds-photo-sharing-features)

Method 2: By using [Starry Hope Uploader](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/starry-hope-facebook-photo-uploader-linux)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jimjimovich/starry-hope-uploader
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install starry-hope-uploader
```

Update: **Method 3** is here.

you can also upload the images to facebook from shotwell image viewer in your Ubuntu.
to enable that feature open system settings > online accounts

There add your facebook account and then at account option enable shotwell to upload your images to facebook

[image]